# A weakly continuous semigroup of operators on a Banach Space is Strongly Continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

The following is an exercise from Dunford & Schwartz (1958) page 653.

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T_t:X \to X$ be a semigroup of bounded operators indexes by $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$. Suppose it's continuous w.r.t the weak operator topology, i.e. 
$$\forall \; x \in X, \; y^* \in X^*, \; t \to y^*(T_t(x)) \; cont.$$
**Prove that it's strongly continuous**, i.e. $t \to T_tx$ is norm continuous for all $x\in X$.

What I Tried:

Obviously we can only prove continuity at $t=0$, and one can show using applications of the uniform boundness principle that $\Vert T_t \Vert \leq Me^{ct}$. And From here we can reuce to the case of a semigroup of *contractions* on a Banach Space. But In general, I am not sure that if $x_n \overset{w}{\to} x$ weakly and $\underset{n\to \infty}{limsup}\Vert x_n \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert$ then there is norm convergence.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that if $x_n$ converges weakly to $x$ then $$\|x\|\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|$$

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't see how it helps us here, the limsup condition is the other direction, and even with it I don't see how to prove strong convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This result is a theorem (with proof) in [Engel's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=EKlppf5Nm08C&pg=PA5&dq=%22is+strongly+continuous+if+and+only+if+it+is+weakly+continuous%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCwIDZk9jiAhWiDrkGHUa3C5UQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22is%20strongly%20continuous%20if%20and%20only%20if%20it%20is%20weakly%20continuous%22&f=false).

Comment: Spectacular book! Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @pitariver The [extended version](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=One-Parameter+Semigroups+for+Linear+Evolution+Equations&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPoZ30itviAhWsLLkGHVTKDmcQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=One-Parameter%20Semigroups%20for%20Linear%20Evolution%20Equations&f=false) is also great.